# Win10 Reverting from update 1703 to 1607 without accessing Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10-v1607, windows-10-v1703

Okay, the thing is.
The update was nugging long  enough to make me update it now, after restarting my PC it caused my USB ports to not function at all, this means no keyboard/mouse/wireless adapter.

I can't access my Windows installation (setup on my SSD) to revert it.
What I did manage to do, is set up an old HDD that uses Win10u1511 where the keyboard and mouse work.

How can I revert the Win10u1703 to Win10u1607 on my SSD, from a completely different Win installation set up on an old HDD?

Note, I do have both Windows.old and $WINDOWS.~BT on my SSD.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: You can’t.  It isn’t as simple as removing an windows update.

Comment: Is there any solution to this? I mean.. there must be something I can do to gain access to my Windows installation on the SSD with my keyboard and mouse working.... Presently, I can't even login into my Windows user on my SSD because obviously - the keyboard isn't working (probably due to the newly installed drivers related to USB handling by Windows). I tried tackling this for hours to no avail, no idea what to do...

Comment: Is there a way to maybe install a clean install on top of the locked one instead? If so, would there be a way to use the Windows.old and $WINDOWS.~BT directories to recover some of the settings/files associated with the old installation? @Ramhound

Comment: If you do a clean install your personal files will be lost.  To be clear, you cannot choose to keep your personal files, if your booting to WinRE.  This has always been the case, you can’t do an in-place upgrade, if you do not start the installation from within Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound That's exactly why I'm backing up as many files as I can by copying them from the SSD to a third HDD right now. Heck, I'm even copying the entire user directory (including the desktop and "my documents" folder :P), hopefully that would work somehow.

Any chance that would work?

Comment: Once you backup your files.  You should be able to cause Windows to fail to boot 3 times, this should allow you to get to your Recovery Options/Advanced Startup, allowing you to boot while in safe mode.  At this point you can attempt to roll back the update or find the problem driver

Comment: @Ramhound Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66249/discussion-between-coremodule-and-ramhound).

Answer (score 0):

The key point is that you cannot do any operation on your Windows 10 1703.

Otherwise, you can roll back to Window 10 1607 within 10 days after upgrading:

**Settings > Update & security > Recovery > Go back to an earlier build**

For now, the only method is Clean install Windows 10 1607 using the installation media.